# JPA - @ManyToMany with duplicate reference to the same foreign key

Tags: java, jpa

I have 3 entities like this:

```
@Entity
public class A {

    @Id
    private String id;

}

@Entity
@IdClass(B.BPK.class)
public class B {

    @Id
    private String id;
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    private A a;

}

@Entity
public class C {

    @Id
    private int refOne;
    @Id
    private int refTwo;    
    @Id
    private A a;
    @ManyToMany
    private Set<B> bs;

}
```

I have a question about the table generated for the relation @ManyToMany of the entity C. There are 5 columns generated: refOne, refTwo, a_id, b_id, b_a_id.

As you could see, a_id and b_a_id are foreign key on the same column and in my model, it's not possible that a_id is different from b_a_id.

Is there a solution to not duplicate the column?

**EDIT:**

I insist on this point, A is part of the id of C, and bs in C could be empty.

I think about several solutions but none of them are really satisfying:

- Use a Converter that used the b_id and a_id to recover bs entities
- I tried to manage the columns with @JoinTable like this:

JoinTable approach:

```
@JoinTable(name = "bs", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "refOne", referencedColumnName = "refOne"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "refTwo", referencedColumnName = "refTwo"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "a_id", referencedColumnName = "a_id")
    }, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "b_id", referencedColumnName = "b_id"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "b_a_id", referencedColumnName = "b_a_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
```

But I face theses problems `Mixing insertable and non insertable columns in a property is not allowed or`Parameter index out of range`
        })

Answer (score 0):

Since C has already a reference to A, you can fetch A.bs, without having to declare a collection of bs inside C. You need, however, to have a `Set<B>` in entity A.

Unless, of course, you can't change the mapping...

Comment: There is no meaning to have the `bs` in A in my model. :)

Comment: Generally speaking, if B references A, then A can reference a collection of Bs... if the "meaning" you're talking about is related to your application model, you might be right, I can't argue with that

Comment: Yes it's an application model "constraint". And in fact A is a really  important object and as it is used very often, I have to make it lighter as possible.

Comment: whell then, @XtremeBaumer 's solution might be a better solution for you. Or use a lazy initialization for the collection, and fetch it only when necessary

Answer (score 0):

You could annotate `private A a;` with `@JoinColumn` that references `b_a_id`. There are also other annotations which let you you configure the mapping even more. Yet there is no issue with having 2 FK columns containing the same value.

---

Also you should always create your tables by hand. DOn't let it be generated in production.

---

For more info read the [docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html). Maybe you have to search for a more specific problem, but resources are out there

Comment: But as you could see, A in C is a part of the key. bs can be empty. I edit my post.

Comment: Then you add `@JoinColumns` to your `@ManyToMany` where it references `a_id` and `b_id`